# Angular http calls not executing asynchronously

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I think I'm confused as to how and when to implement the `.then` and/or `.success` functions.

Below is function,

```
$scope.getResults = function(choice){

    if(choice == 1){
        url = firstUrl/;
    }else{
        url = secondUrl/;
    }

    var data = {some: info};

    $http.post(url, data).then(function(response){

        $http.get('profileUrl/'+response.data.contactId[0])
       .then(function(contactResponse){
            //set contactResponse to approproate $scope variables
        });

    });

    if(choice == 1){
        choice = 2;
        $scope.getResults(2);
    }

}
```

The call to the above function is made as, `$scope.getResults(1)`. `firstUrl` only returns 50 results which is quite fast but the `secondUrl` loads 100K results which is time consuming. For some reason the `profileUrl` does not return results until I get the response from `secondUrl`.

Can you tell me what can I do here so that the `profileUrl` returns the result and is not stuck waiting for the response from `secondUrl`?

Comment: return ` $http.get('profileUrl/'+response.data.contactId[0])` in another then

Comment: Looking at your code, the profileUrl call depends on the response from the http.post. You are appending to the profileUrl the contactId from the response of secondUrl.  How can you not wait for the response of secondUrl?

Comment: @Sasang can you please suggest an alternate way I'm not well versed with angular

Comment: I think your problem as Sasang suggested is when the `choice != 1` you still need to wait for the response, not matter what because is depending on the second request.

Comment: So what i'm saying is, the way you have your APIs set up. It looks like you need the contactId from secondUrl to make any calls to profileUrl. Its not really a matter of changing the angular code, you would need to alter your API structure so that porfileUrl is not dependent on the response from secondUrl

Comment: Also, why are you have this condition twice: `if(choice == 1){`

Comment: @Sasang `contactId` will be returned from both `firstUrl` and `secondUrl` so I need to call `profileUrl` twice. The problem is I'm seeing the HTTP call to `profileUrl` but I'm not getting the response unless I get the response from `secondUrl`

Comment: Lets go through this logically, and lets only consider the case for `secondUrl`. You just said that `contactId` is returned by `secondUrl`, and we know that `profileUrl` needs `contactId` to make its request, so what choice is there but to wait for `contactId` and only then calling `profileUrl`.

Comment: @Sasang `contactId` is returned by both `firstUrl` and `secondUrl`

Answer (score 0):

```
$http.post('controller/url',$.param({val: value}),config)
        .success(function (response){
            console.log(response);
        })
```